# kdiff3 1.8.01 seems completely broken on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, kde

- the merge menu is incomplete. all the choose A/B/C everywhere, or choose A/B/C for all unresolved ... are missing.
- the open file dialogue does not show any file at all but only directories.

Are these known bugs? Any work around for this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is broken. I don't know of any bug reports, but building version 1.8.3 from git at least gives me the files in *Open* dialog back. Here's how I did it:

```
sudo apt remove kdiff3
sudo apt build-dep kdiff3
git clone https://github.com/KDE/kdiff3
cd kdiff3
git checkout 1.8.3
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/opt/kdiff3
make
make install
```

After this I can run my own copy of `kdiff3` as `~/opt/kdiff3/bin/kdiff3`. You may want to tweak your `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to match your needs.

NOTE: don't try to install git `master` (at least as of `c2704be2e44`): it's broken even more than the stock Ubuntu's version (crashes on startup due to multiple typos and some other errors).

I suggest that you file your own bug report (if you too fail to find an existing one).

Comment: I was to install next dependencies to build kdiff3 from source on Ubuntu 20.04:
`extra-cmake-modules libkf5crash-dev libkf5iconthemes-dev libkf5doctools-dev libkf5parts-dev`

Comment: @Suthiro didn't `apt build-dep` install them?

Comment: unfortunately, no. I don't know why.

Comment: I found a bug report for Debian  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=962960

Answer (score 0):

update ubuntu to 20.10. Kdiff work ok.